# How to detect if users browser is AVG via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, browser, user-agent

How I can detect if the user is using AVG as a browser?

If I go to Google and I type in what is my useragent, then AVG/100.xxx is mentioned, but when I use `navigator.userAgent`, the AVG part is not there.

What am I missing?

Comment: Try to see if this detects it correctly. https://faisalman.github.io/ua-parser-js/#demo. Then you might be able to use that.

Comment: thx for the info but is not getting detected...
When using the debugger, I see that the useragent does not contain any indidation of the avast browser. So how does google know ... mystery....

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the trick. By looking further in the debugger, I found out that you can grab the info via the ua client hints.

```js
navigator.userAgentData.getHighEntropyValues(["platform"])
.then(ua => {console.log(ua)});
```